# Java Binding Library generating two members with same name but different return types

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xpath, xamarin.android

I am creating a Java/Android Binding Library using .AAR files. After compiling the C# Bindings Library project, it generates this error:

`Type 'PushMessageHandler' already defines a member called 'A' with the same parameter types`

The problem is a class contains these two methods, with the same name but different return types:

```
// Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.xiaomi.mipush.sdk']/class[@name='PushMessageHandler']/method[@name='a' and count(parameter)=0]"
[Register ("a", "()V", "")]
protected static unsafe void A ()
{
    const string __id = "a.()V";
    try {
        _members.StaticMethods.InvokeVoidMethod (__id, null);
    } finally {
    }
}

// Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.xiaomi.mipush.sdk']/class[@name='PushMessageHandler']/method[@name='a' and count(parameter)=0]"
[Register ("a", "()Z", "GetAHandler")]
protected override unsafe bool A ()
{
    const string __id = "a.()Z";
    try {
        var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualBooleanMethod (__id, this, null);
        return __rm;
    } finally {
    }
}
```

But as you can see, the XPath method reference is the same for both methods:
`path="/api/package[@name='com.xiaomi.mipush.sdk']/class[@name='PushMessageHandler']/method[@name='a' and count(parameter)=0]"`

Therefore, when I try to change the method name of one of the methods in `Metadata.xml`, it changes the name of both methods and the same error persists.

**Is there a way I can change the name of just one of the methods**? (Specifically the method with the void return type). Is there a way to include the return type in the XPath method reference?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging around the api.xml file, as well as some trial and error, I found you can add `@return='void'` inside the `method[...]` part to target the specific method:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.xiaomi.mipush.sdk']/class[@name='PushMessageHandler']/method[@name='a' and count(parameter)=0 and @return='void']" name="managedName">AVoid</attr>
```